# Can I simultaneously connect both a MacBook Pro and a Mac mini to the same Cinema Display 27?

Tags: macbook, display, connector, mac-mini

I am about to buy a Led Cinema Display 27, but I wonder if I can connect both the Mac mini and my MacBook Pro without the need of unplugging the Mac mini all the time. From [what I see](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html) there is just one connection cable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think you'd probably have to use a Mini DisplayPort KVM switch like [this one](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-2x1-Mini-DisplayPort-KVM-Switch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Clicking "Buy now" [gets one](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC007LL/A) a page that includes a link to [the Questions & Answers](http://store.apple.com/us/questions/product/MC007LL/A), with many questions you might want to browse through. Like: is the cable long enough to get to a computer that is underneath your desk?

As for your question, there is [an answer](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MC007LL/A?pqid=QPYK4JJCA9TKD4KF9KADUKXC2KH7JPYKT), but I do NOT know how authoritative it is:

> Is it possible to have multiple inputs on this monitor? i.e.MacBook Pro connected via DisplayPort as well a laptop connected via a VGA to DisplayPort? With a way of switching between them etc
>
> No. You can only hook up one Mac at the time.